# Apache virtual host serves default vhost for port 443 despite server name match for port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have two servers that are clones of each other save for a few minor configuration changes. I am getting some unexpected behaviour when trying to visit their monitoring.*.com sub domains.

Running `./apache2ctl -S` on each server gives the following:

Staging Server

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
     default server 010.staging.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/010:2)
     port 443 namevhost 010.staging.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/010:2)
     port 443 namevhost 011.staging.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/011:2)
     port 443 namevhost 013.staging.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/013:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server www.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost www.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost monitoring.staging.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/monitoring:1)
Syntax OK
```

Production Server

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
     default server de.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/de:2)
     port 443 namevhost de.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/de:2)
     port 443 namevhost uk.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/uk:2)
     port 443 namevhost us.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/us:2)
     port 443 namevhost www.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/production:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server www.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost www.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost monitoring.production.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/monitoring:1)
Syntax OK
```

The configuration of 000-default is as follows on both servers

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.production.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/apache/
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteLog      /var/log/apache2/log
    RewriteLogLevel 1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/     !^(/server-status).*$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$             https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I am having is that when I visit `http://monitoring.staging.com` I am being redirected to `http**s**.monitoring.staging.com` and being served the app for `010.staging.com` the default secure port server.

The production server is behaving as expected and serving my application monitoring tool.

As I said both these servers started out as clones of a master image with only very minor configuration changes - I can describe specific changes if needed.

Can anyone hazard any guesses why I am seeing this behaviour?

Thank you

---

Updates:

This is the Vhost config for monitoring:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName  monitoring.staging.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/munin
    <Directory /var/www/munin>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
    LogLevel notice
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

And for the app that is actually being served:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 010.staging.com
    RewriteLog      /var/log/apache2/ssl.log
    RewriteRule ^/$                                         /010/home.htm [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(?!010/|static/|mgt).*$   /010/home.htm [R=301,L]
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/010/apache.key
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/010/apache.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/010/apache-ca.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What kind of redirect are you getting - which response code?  Would the application running in that monitoring vhost be redirecting?  Otherwise, do you have anything in the config files or in an htaccess file that would have a redirect to `https` configured?

Comment: I am getting a 301 redirect to httpS://monitoring.staging.com when requesting http://monitoring.staging.com

Comment: The app that should be delivered by monitoring is just a default Munin installation and does not perform any redirections. I will include the vhost file for monitoring

Comment: I'm beginning to think that maybe it's staging that is working as expected and production that's squiffy but then the mystery is why production working at all?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by change the `000-default` config on staging to the follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName staging.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/apache/
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteLog      /var/log/apache2/log
    RewriteLogLevel 1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/     !^(/server-status).*$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$             https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The change being the ServerName from www.production.com to staging.com

I don't know **why** this fixed the issue so I am more than happy give a correct answer tick to anyone that can explain the behaviour and what Apache is doing.

Comment: Hmm.. your browser should have never hit the `000-default` vhost for a request to `monitoring.production.com`, but the change to that file fixed it.. so we will need to figure out why that vhost got the request.  Did your browser maybe stick a `www` on the front?

Comment: Nope, no extra www from the browser. I get the same results with the HTTPClient.app for OS X.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you fire up a `RewriteLog` with `RewriteLogLevel` set high to see what's going on with mod_rewrite?